# Pushing text value of a checkbox in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have two checkboxes like :

```
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="Status"/> 
</div>
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="FirstName"/>
</div>
```

I have an array like

```
string[] arrchk = new string[] { };
```

How can I store the text value of the checkboxes in the array

Comment: Why don't use [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ??

Comment: srikanta, take time. address your issue properly. what do you want?

Comment: I have those check boxes in an asp.net page, I want to get the text values of those checkboxes, and then I want to create a datatable whose column name is same as the checkboxe's text.

Comment: Why can't you use `table.Columns.Add(CheckBox1.Text)`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning that you want the text values of all checked checkboxes, or the text value of every checkbox, or...?

Either way, you want to iterate through the Page's Controls collection to find all controls that have a type of Checkbox and then use that to get their text values (and you can limit whether you want to include checked boxes or not in that iteration).  And, yes, using a List might be easier than starting with an array, because you can easily add to a List<> and then transform it into an array with little pain.